# Nginx or application cuts part of URI

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have this chain of proxy: nginx proxies to my internal nginx, which proxies to tomcat

main nginx:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

access_log /var/log/nginx/eco.access.log main;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/eco.error.log;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
  index index.html;
}

location /analytics {
  proxy_pass http://10.89.81.130:80/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
}
```

internal nginx:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 = /error404_nx.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

     location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html;
     }        

    location /ords {
          rewrite ^\/ords\/f.p(.*)$ /analytics/ords/$1 break;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
          proxy_redirect off;

          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    }
```

I expect request will be /analytics/ords/..., but as a result /ords/... without analytics and i get 404 error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your main `nginx` use:

```
location /analytics/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.89.81.130:80/;
    ...
}
```

Notice the additional `/`. This causes the URI to be aliased from `/analytics/ords` to `/ords` before it is received by the internal `nginx`. Which is then passed unmodified as `/ords` to port 8080.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.